# Why Am I Getting This NSManaged Object Error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data

Getting error at line `[theSelectedRoutine addExerciseObject: exercise];` saying method -addExerciseObject not found.

Interface:
@property (nonatomic, retain) Routine *theSelectedRoutine;

```
-(void)addExercise
{   
    if (managedObjectContext == nil) 
    { 
        managedObjectContext = [(CurlAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext]; 
        [managedObjectContext retain];
    }

    UIBarButtonItem *addButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(exerciseChooser)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = addButton;
    [addButton release];

    NSError *error = nil;

    Exercise *exercise = (Exercise *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Exercise" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];

    exercise.name = selectedExercise;

    [theSelectedRoutine addExerciseObject: exercise];

    if (![managedObjectContext save:&error]) 
    {
        // Handle the error.
    }
    NSLog(@"%@", error);

    [self.routineTableView reloadData];

}
```

..

```
Routine Class
#import "Routine.h"
#import "Exercise.h"


@implementation Routine
@dynamic name;
@dynamic timeStamp;
@dynamic routineExercises;

- (void)addRoutineExercisesObject:(Exercise *)value {    
    NSSet *changedObjects = [[NSSet alloc] initWithObjects:&value count:1];
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"routineExercises" withSetMutation:NSKeyValueUnionSetMutation usingObjects:changedObjects];
    [[self primitiveValueForKey:@"routineExercises"] addObject:value];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"routineExercises" withSetMutation:NSKeyValueUnionSetMutation usingObjects:changedObjects];
    [changedObjects release];
}

- (void)removeRoutineExercisesObject:(Exercise *)value {
    NSSet *changedObjects = [[NSSet alloc] initWithObjects:&value count:1];
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"routineExercises" withSetMutation:NSKeyValueMinusSetMutation usingObjects:changedObjects];
    [[self primitiveValueForKey:@"routineExercises"] removeObject:value];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"routineExercises" withSetMutation:NSKeyValueMinusSetMutation usingObjects:changedObjects];
    [changedObjects release];
}

- (void)addRoutineExercises:(NSSet *)value {    
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"routineExercises" withSetMutation:NSKeyValueUnionSetMutation usingObjects:value];
    [[self primitiveValueForKey:@"routineExercises"] unionSet:value];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"routineExercises" withSetMutation:NSKeyValueUnionSetMutation usingObjects:value];
}

- (void)removeRoutineExercises:(NSSet *)value {
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"routineExercises" withSetMutation:NSKeyValueMinusSetMutation usingObjects:value];
    [[self primitiveValueForKey:@"routineExercises"] minusSet:value];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"routineExercises" withSetMutation:NSKeyValueMinusSetMutation usingObjects:value];
}


@end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I don't see `addExerciseObject` either, shouldn't it be `[theSelectedRoutine addRoutineExercisesObject:exercise];` ?

Comment: I've tried that too, but I still get the same error.  It says saying method -addRoutineExercisesObject not found (return type defaults to 'id').

Comment: is this method's prototype in the `.h` file?

Comment: No it wasn't.  Youre right the error is gone now.  I would have thought they would have generated the method in the .h automatically.